# In Xcode logs what does '[number1:number2]' mean?

Tags: xcode

What does`[10691:1443128]` mean in Xcode log messages?

`2019-12-05 20:43:12.797600+1300 testingLogs[10691:1443128] Hello World`

[image: xcode debug messsage]

Comment: I think the first one is the process id, not sure about the second. Maybe someone else will find the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Process ID and Thread ID.

https://riptutorial.com/objective-c/example/2440/nslog-output-format

Curiously I couldn't find any mention of thread ID in [Apple documentation that elaborated on NSLog/debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2347/_index.html).